# Are global structs allocated on the stack or on the heap?

Tags: c++, struct

I am writing in an environment where I am not allowed to allocate new memory after program startup, nor am I allowed to make operating system calls.  In tracking down a page fault error (likely caused by inadvertently violating one of the above) the question occurs to me (since this bit me in the butt with std strings)

Is a global/local struct allocated on the stack or heap?  For example:

If this statement is in the global scope

```
struct symbol {
    char blockID;
    int blockNum;
    int ivalue;  
    double fvalue;
    int reference;
    bool isFloat, isInt, isRef;
    int symbolLength;
} mySymbol;
```

where is the memory for it allocated?

Comment: I may be grasping at straws but I'm trying to resolve a rather irritating problem and running out of ideas.

Comment: Neither on the heap, nor on the stack but in in the memory for global objects.

Comment: BTW, you can make your own heap with a large global object.  Combine that with a custom `std::allocator` and you can safely use `std::string`, `std::vector`, etc.

Comment: Have you considered overriding `::operator new` to either ASSERT, exception, or use a statically allocated pool?

Comment: @deft_code `@Mooing Duck I hadn't considered either of these possibilities, but I will think about using them.  Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's implementation-defined (the C++ standard doesn't really talk about stack and heap).

Typically, objects with static storage duration (such as globals) will end up in a special segment of address space that is neither stack nor heap.  But the specifics vary from platform to platform.

Comment: I didn't think they would be handled in any special way, but I wanted to be confident that there was no memory allocation happening in the background.  If the object was declared within a function scope, would it then appear on the stack?

Comment: @Stephen: Yes.  Non-static local variables (more formally, variables with *automatic storage duration*) appear on the stack.

Answer (score 11):

In C++, unlike in C#, `struct` makes few differences with `class`. A `struct` is a `class` whose default visibility is public. Whether the allocation is performed on the stack or in the heap depends on the way you allocate your instance

```
class A;

void f()
{
 A a;//stack allocated
 A *a1 = new A();// heap
}
```